# which format of XmlTextWriter for answer xmlhttprequest

Tags: .net, ashx, xmltextwriter

for answer a xmlhttprequest in .ashx file with xml that created with XmlTextWriter class  how I must Outputting it ? to a file/string/memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to write to `Response.OutputStream`. You can do this by providing the stream as parameter when instantiating the `XmlTextWriter`.

You may want to clear and/or set appropriate response headers, too.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you want to be writing it to the client, so something like

```
context.Response.OutputStream
```

would be a reasonable output stream to write to.